# XSLT Order classes in a non-alphabetical non-numerical order

Tags: xslt

I have researched this problem but the suggestions that I have found seems to be rather convoluted and for a more general scenario. Perhaps there is a more concise solution for this scenario, that is more specific.

I have a large number of html files like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>t</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="f">f1</div>
      <div class="e">e1</div>
      <div class="e">e2</div>
      <div class="g">g</div>
      <div class="c">c1</div>
      <div class="b">
        <div class="ba">ba</div>
        <div class="bb">bb</div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">c2</div>
      <div class="f">f2</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
      <div class="c">c3</div>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

**Rule # 1**
I want to order the div's inside div class="a" in a specific order of their class attribute that is non-alphabetic and non-numeric. For the purpose of this example, let's the final order be the following:

- g
- f
- b
- c
- e
- d

In my real examples, the list is much longer.

**Rule # 2**
If for a given class attribute there is more than one node, then they should be left in the same order as in the original file, for instance:

- c1
- c2
- c3

Please notice that in my real examples these values would not be in alphanumerical order.

**Rule # 3**
The order of child nodes must not be affected, for instance:

- ba
- bb

Please notice that in my real examples these values would not be in alphanumerical order either.

The final output should be like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>t</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="g">g</div>
      <div class="f">f1</div>
      <div class="f">f2</div>
      <div class="b">
        <div class="ba">ba</div>
        <div class="bb">bb</div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">c1</div>
      <div class="c">c2</div>
      <div class="c">c3</div>
      <div class="e">e1</div>
      <div class="e">e2</div>
      <div class="d">d</div>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I have thought at first to:

1. Prepend a number to the class attribute value, for instance rename class="g" to class="01g", etc
2. Order the classes in alphanumerical order
3. Remove the number, for instance rename class="01g" to class = "g", etc

However I dislike this solution because it requires too many transformations.

What I would really like is to come up with a more elegant solutions. Perhaps I would define an ordered list of class values and a clever index would somehow put the nodes in that defined order?

Do you have any suggestions to add to my xslt template?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't understand your 1st rule. If the order is "*non-alphabetic and non-numeric*" then what is it exactly? If it's arbitrary, then how would prepending a number help?

Comment: The order is an arbitrary order defined by the user. For example first the nodes with class="definition", then class="item", then class="example", etc. I have abstracted this rule in my example by creating an arbitrary order: g, f, b, c, e, d. I was thinking of renaming them to 01definition, 02item, 03example, etc, and then finding a transformation that uses the first two digits for my order. However (even if I find such a transformation, and I haven't yet), I would still need to rename the classes to their original names at the end, which makes the whole idea rather convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
    <xsl:variable name="sort-order">gfbced</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, @class))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To accommodate class values that are not single characters, you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
    <xsl:variable name="sort-order">|g|f|b|c|e|d|</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, concat('|', @class, '|')))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the exact type of concise solution I was striving for. I can see now the two pieces that I couldn't come up with by myself. Tested and it all works.