# XSLT sort input in arbitrary order

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm pretty new to XSLT. I did my fair amount of research on the web however I could not find enough information that suit my case.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a large XML document with 10 to 15 sections. The structure more or less looks like the following:

```
<headerSection>
    <!-- lots of stuff in here -->
</headerSection>
<containerSection>
    <bodySection>
        <container1>
            <container2>
                <identifier code="12345"/>
                <!-- lots of stuff in here -->
            </container2>
        </container1>
        <container1>
            <container2>
                <identifier code="98765"/>
                <!-- lots of stuff in here -->
            </container2>
        </container1>
    </bodySection>
</containerSection>
```

I have an XSL file that I apply to this in order to output a styled HTML page.
Now, what I want to do is to render the children of the `<bodySection>` in an arbitrary order. The criteria for determining the order is the `code` attribute in the `<identifier>` element. 
Let me clarify once more that the ordering should be arbitrary.

I understand that I can do this with an `xsl:sort` directive, however I'm a huge XSL newbie and I don't quite get how to use it from the examples I've found online. 
 The main point is that I'm generating a styled HTML page, not "just" transforming the XML input.

What looks like to be the closest to what I'm trying to do is this snippet:

```
<xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'professionalsection,educationalsection'"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(
                                 substring-before(
                                    concat(',',$pOrder,','),
                                    concat(',',name(),',')))"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately I'm not very sure about how to used it in my case.
Intuitively, I would try and change the values pointed at in `select="'professionalsection,educationalsection'"` but is this the right approach?
Any help is very appreciated!

**UPDATE**

By looking at the example posted in the comment, I came up with this. I hope it gives a more clear picture of what I'm trying to do:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bodySection">
    <xsl:variable name="sort-order">|98765|12345|</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, concat('|', container1/container2/identifier/@code, '|')))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above snippet doesn't work yet. The result I'm trying to achieve would look like:

```
    <headerSection>
    <!-- lots of stuff in here -->
</headerSection>
<containerSection>
    <bodySection>
        <container1>
            <container2>
                <identifier code="98765"/>
                <!-- lots of stuff in here -->
            </container2>
        </container1>
        <container1>
            <container2>
                <identifier code="12345"/>
                <!-- lots of stuff in here -->
            </container2>
        </container1>
    </bodySection>
</containerSection>
```

...where the elements `container1` (along with their children) are swapped.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409952/xslt-order-classes-in-a-non-alphabetical-non-numerical-order/38410077#38410077 If not, expand your question so we can understand the required logic: you say you want to sort by the `code` value, but there are no codes with values of `professionalsection` or `educationalsection`in your example.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. You don't see the `code` attribute in `professionalsection` because that is the snippet I found online that looks most promising. 
I'm trying to adapt it to my case: 

what I've come up so far is: 
<xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, concat('|', container1/container2/identifier/@code, '|')))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

Comment: Well, that's not helpful in understanding what *your* question is. Anyway, I hope you've found your answer.

Comment: I've updated my queston. Hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the ordering should be arbitrary". "Arbitrary" means "based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system." Do you want the order to be random, or do you want it to be unpredictable, or do you not care what the order is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sort-order, concat('|', container2/identifier/@code, '|')))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The output is identical to the input

Comment: It works indeed! It didn't at first because I forgot to declare the correct namespace prefixes. Thank you very much Michael