# XSLT sort groups of element in specific order

Tags: xslt

I have a list of items which i group according to their category, but now i want to sort the groups in a specific order. For example instead of Group GH, Group XT, Group ABC i want: Group XT, Group ABC, Group GH.

im grouping elements this way:

```
  <xsl:template match="/udt:UserDefinedTable">
    <xsl:for-each select="udt:Data[count(. | key('data-by-Category', udt:Category)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:sort select="udt:Zap" />
      <span class="NameofFunction">
        <h3>
          <xsl:value-of select="udt:Category" disable-output-escaping="yes" />&#160;</h3>
      </span>
      <xsl:variable name="currentData" select="key('data-by-Category', udt:Category)" />
      <xsl:if test="$currentData">
        <div class="row">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

I guess i would have to add a field on each item to specific the group order, so all items of Group XT would have value of 'groupsort' = 1. So selecting the groupsort vlaue of first child and then sort the groups accordingly, right? Any help is appreciated. (Again: i want to sort groups themselves not the elements inside groups).

Comment: So do you know all those possible values like `Group XT` when you write the stylesheet? Or do the depend on the particular input? In the latter case, what determines the order?

Comment: Users input items where they specify a category like 'Group XT', but they may enter anything, anything entered will be a new group.
I want to add a groupsort field on each item so i can enter numbers, and then check this value on first child of each group to determine the order of groups

Comment: There is no user input in XSLT. If you have a known sort order - either constant or passed as a parameter - you can use the method shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503038/xslt-sort-input-in-arbitrary-order/38504888#38504888

Comment: i have a user input for data via a module, which uses xslt to display the data

Comment: The input to XSLT is an XML document. If the sort order is included in there, then you can access it as any other data. Or you can use the calling application to pass it as a parameter to the XSLT stylesheet at runtime. Otherwise it doesn't exist, as far the XSLT stylesheet is concerned.